# Error in create new user with PHP SDK

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am currently getting an error trying to create a new user with a PHP SDK

1. [Parse Platform](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/issues/55)
2. [Post Image](http://postimg.org/image/e8e08c2m1/)

**ERROR OUTPUT**

```
You must specify a Parse class name or register the appropriate subclass when creating a new Object. Use ParseObject::create to create a subclass object.
```

**PHP FILE**

```
$user = new ParseUser();
$user->set("username", "test");
$user->set("email", "test@gmail.com");
$user->set("password", "Cf%09ude");

try {
    $user->signUp();
    $result = true;
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
    echo "Error: " . $ex->getCode() . " " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Please be more specific, what you want to achive, what error do you get, etc...

Comment: ERROR Exception:
You must specify a Parse class name or register the appropriate subclass when creating a new Object. Use ParseObject::create to create a subclass object.

Comment: The error tells everything. I think, you should use: `$user = ParseUser::create();` with the parameters.

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/php_guide#users-signup

Comment: ParseObject::create does not work.

Comment: yes, I've see that before i read the doc. I do not have idea.

Comment: I do not know what else to do.

http://postimg.org/image/e8e08c2m1/

Comment: If you see why the error is being thrown why can't you provide the necessary inputs? I don't understand. Your code here is almost meaningless and you left out a large part in your image (like what method that is).

Comment: I simply want to register a new user within the Parse.com

By using a class provided by the documentation, this error occurs.

This image is the only information that is shown to generate this error.

Sorry for the incomplete information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to initialize your SDK with `ParseClient::initialize`. The correct usage after loading the `autoload.php` is:

```
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;

$app_id = 'your_app_id';
$rest_key = 'your_rest_key';
$master_key = 'your_master_key';

ParseClient::initialize($app_id, $rest_key, $master_key);

$user = new ParseUser();
$user->set("username", "test");
$user->set("email", "test@gmail.com");
$user->set("password", "Cf%09ude");

try {
    $user->signUp();
    $result = true;
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
    echo "Error: " . $ex->getCode() . " " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

The above code was tested and works with the correct API keys filled in - and I was able to reproduce your error by commenting out the `ParseClient::initialize` line. I've [submitted a Pull Request to GitHub](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/pull/56) to show a more descriptive exception for this scenario.

Comment: Thank sjagr.

I was developing the wrong way, including the initialize in a constructor.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$user= ParseUser::create('_User');
```

This is how a user is created in [the source](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseUser.php#l180).

Comment: Would you add some explanatory text as to how this answers the question? Your answer is short enough to have been featured in the review queue, and without a bit more material, it may be deleted. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer From the source: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseUser.php#l180[/link]